# Flashplayer processes not closing when testing in flex / flashbuilder

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-builder

Having this new problem with flash builder where I run a debug flashplayer, close out the flash and it doesn't always kill the process. Sometimes it does sometimes it doesn't, leaving me, after a while, having 10 or more flashplayer tabs on windows still open. I try to close them using the task manager with no luck.

This hasn't always happened, anyone experience this as well or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Browser projects or Adobe AIR Projects?  I've never seen this in Web projects.  But, in Adobe AIR projects, when this occurs I usually can't launch a new debug session until I force quit.

I browser based, does your browser close when you terminate the debug session?  If not, try to shut down the browser manually before launching a new debug session.

I'm sorry I don't have specific answers.  I you expand on your Operating System, browser choice, and version of Flash Player it may help others.

Comment: Just propjects in general that I am testing from Flashbuilder. Most of them browser projects, but I'm compiling directly to the flashplayer, not the browser.

Comment: What do you mean that you're compiling directly to the Flash Player?  Flex always compiles down to SWFs; however usually those SWFs are run in a browser, or within Adobe AIR.  Are you using a standalone version of the Flash Player?  And launching that standalone player from Flash Builder?